# Shell command works on direct hosts but fail on Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a problem with executing a script using the shell module with Ansible.

1. When I run the command directly on remote server:

   ```
   [root@ansible-agent-1 kong-rpm]# ./migrations.sh
   ```

The output

```
Bootstrapping database...
migrating core on keyspace 'kong'...
core migrated up to: 000_base (executed)
core migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
core migrated up to: 002_15_to_1 (executed)
2021/12/25 14:56:28 [warn] ignored error while running '003_100_to_110' migration: [Invalid]   Invalid column na                                          me protocols because it conflicts with an existing column (ALTER TABLE plugins ADD protocols set<text>)
2021/12/25 14:56:28 [warn] ignored error while running '003_100_to_110' migration: [Invalid] Invalid column na                                          me tags because it conflicts with an existing column (ALTER TABLE plugins ADD tags set<text>)
core migrated up to: 003_100_to_110 (executed)
core migrated up to: 004_110_to_120 (executed)
migrating hmac-auth on keyspace 'kong'...
hmac-auth migrated up to: 000_base_hmac_auth (executed)
hmac-auth migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
migrating oauth2 on keyspace 'kong'...
oauth2 migrated up to: 000_base_oauth2 (executed)
oauth2 migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
oauth2 migrated up to: 002_15_to_10 (executed)
migrating jwt on keyspace 'kong'...
jwt migrated up to: 000_base_jwt (executed)
jwt migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
migrating basic-auth on keyspace 'kong'...
basic-auth migrated up to: 000_base_basic_auth (executed)
basic-auth migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
migrating key-auth on keyspace 'kong'...
key-auth migrated up to: 000_base_key_auth (executed)
key-auth migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
migrating acl on keyspace 'kong'...
acl migrated up to: 000_base_acl (executed)
acl migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
migrating response-ratelimiting on keyspace 'kong'...
response-ratelimiting migrated up to: 000_base_response_rate_limiting (executed)
response-ratelimiting migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
response-ratelimiting migrated up to: 002_15_to_10 (executed)
migrating rate-limiting on keyspace 'kong'...
rate-limiting migrated up to: 000_base_rate_limiting (executed)
rate-limiting migrated up to: 001_14_to_15 (executed)
rate-limiting migrated up to: 002_15_to_10 (executed)
rate-limiting migrated up to: 003_10_to_112 (executed)
25 migrations processed
25 executed
Database is up-to-date
```

The output of command `netstat -antlp`:
[image]

However, when I run this command with Ansible, it fails. The command and error output:

```
   - name: Execute the command in remote shell; stdout goes to the specified file on the remote
     ansible.builtin.shell: /root/kong-resource/kong-rpm/migrations.sh
```

```
fatal: [ansible-agent-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["kong", "migrations", "bootstrap", "-c", "/etc/kong/kong.conf", "--vv"], "delta": "0:00:00.322900", "end": "2021-12-25 14:46:52.724967", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-12-25 14:46:52.402067", "stderr": "Error: \n/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:93: [Cassandra error] all hosts tried for query failed. 192.168.146.129: host seems unhealthy, considering it down (connection refused)\nstack traceback:\n\t[C]: in function 'assert'\n\t/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:93: in function 'cmd_exec'\n\t/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87>\n\t[C]: in function 'xpcall'\n\t/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:44>\n\t/usr/local/bin/kong:7: in function 'file_gen'\n\tinit_worker_by_lua:50: in function <init_worker_by_lua:48>\n\t[C]: in function 'xpcall'\n\tinit_worker_by_lua:57: in function <init_worker_by_lua:55>", "stderr_lines": ["Error: ", "/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:93: [Cassandra error] all hosts tried for query failed. 192.168.146.129: host seems unhealthy, considering it down (connection refused)", "stack traceback:", "\t[C]: in function 'assert'", "\t/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:93: in function 'cmd_exec'", "\t/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87>", "\t[C]: in function 'xpcall'", "\t/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:44>", "\t/usr/local/bin/kong:7: in function 'file_gen'", "\tinit_worker_by_lua:50: in function <init_worker_by_lua:48>", "\t[C]: in function 'xpcall'", "\tinit_worker_by_lua:57: in function <init_worker_by_lua:55>"], "stdout": "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [verbose] Kong: 1.2.2\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] ngx_lua: 10013\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx: 1013006\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] Lua: LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [verbose] reading config file at /etc/kong/kong.conf\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] reading environment variables\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] admin_access_log = \"logs/admin_access.log\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] admin_error_log = \"logs/error.log\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] admin_listen = {\"0.0.0.0:8001\",\"0.0.0.0:8444 ssl\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] anonymous_reports = true\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_consistency = \"ONE\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_contact_points = {\"192.168.146.129\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_data_centers = {\"dc1:2\",\"dc2:3\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_keyspace = \"kong\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_lb_policy = \"RequestRoundRobin\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_password = \"******\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_port = 9042\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_repl_factor = 1\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_repl_strategy = \"SimpleStrategy\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_schema_consensus_timeout = 10000\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_ssl = false\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_ssl_verify = false\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_timeout = 5000\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_username = \"cassandra\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] client_body_buffer_size = \"8k\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] client_max_body_size = \"0\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] client_ssl = false\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] database = \"cassandra\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_cache_ttl = 0\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_cache_warmup_entities = {\"services\",\"plugins\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_resurrect_ttl = 30\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_update_frequency = 5\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_update_propagation = 1\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_error_ttl = 1\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_hostsfile = \"/etc/hosts\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_no_sync = false\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_not_found_ttl = 30\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_order = {\"LAST\",\"SRV\",\"A\",\"CNAME\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_resolver = {}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_stale_ttl = 4\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] error_default_type = \"text/plain\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] headers = {\"server_tokens\",\"latency_tokens\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] log_level = \"notice\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] lua_package_cpath = \"\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] lua_package_path = \"./?.lua;./?/init.lua;\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] lua_socket_pool_size = 30\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] lua_ssl_verify_depth = 1\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] mem_cache_size = \"128m\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_admin_directives = {}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_daemon = \"on\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_http_directives = {}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_optimizations = true\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_proxy_directives = {}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_sproxy_directives = {}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_stream_directives = {}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_user = \"root root\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_worker_processes = \"auto\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] origins = {}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_database = \"kong\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_host = \"127.0.0.1\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_max_concurrent_queries = 0\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_port = 5432\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_semaphore_timeout = 60000\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_ssl = false\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_ssl_verify = false\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_timeout = 5000\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_user = \"kong\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] plugins = {\"bundled\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] prefix = \"/usr/local/kong/\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] proxy_access_log = \"logs/access.log\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] proxy_error_log = \"logs/error.log\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] proxy_listen = {\"0.0.0.0:8000\",\"0.0.0.0:8443 ssl\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] real_ip_header = \"X-Real-IP\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] real_ip_recursive = \"off\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] router_consistency = \"strict\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] ssl_cipher_suite = \"modern\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] ssl_ciphers = \"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256\"\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] stream_listen = {\"off\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] trusted_ips = {\"0.0.0.0/0\"}\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] upstream_keepalive = 60\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [verbose] prefix in use: /usr/local/kong\n2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] resolved Cassandra contact point '192.168.146.129' to: 192.168.146.129", "stdout_lines": ["2021/12/25 14:46:52 [verbose] Kong: 1.2.2", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] ngx_lua: 10013", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx: 1013006", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] Lua: LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [verbose] reading config file at /etc/kong/kong.conf", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] reading environment variables", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] admin_access_log = \"logs/admin_access.log\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] admin_error_log = \"logs/error.log\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] admin_listen = {\"0.0.0.0:8001\",\"0.0.0.0:8444 ssl\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] anonymous_reports = true", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_consistency = \"ONE\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_contact_points = {\"192.168.146.129\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_data_centers = {\"dc1:2\",\"dc2:3\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_keyspace = \"kong\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_lb_policy = \"RequestRoundRobin\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_password = \"******\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_port = 9042", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_repl_factor = 1", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_repl_strategy = \"SimpleStrategy\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_schema_consensus_timeout = 10000", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_ssl = false", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_ssl_verify = false", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_timeout = 5000", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] cassandra_username = \"cassandra\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] client_body_buffer_size = \"8k\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] client_max_body_size = \"0\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] client_ssl = false", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] database = \"cassandra\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_cache_ttl = 0", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_cache_warmup_entities = {\"services\",\"plugins\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_resurrect_ttl = 30", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_update_frequency = 5", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] db_update_propagation = 1", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_error_ttl = 1", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_hostsfile = \"/etc/hosts\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_no_sync = false", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_not_found_ttl = 30", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_order = {\"LAST\",\"SRV\",\"A\",\"CNAME\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_resolver = {}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] dns_stale_ttl = 4", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] error_default_type = \"text/plain\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] headers = {\"server_tokens\",\"latency_tokens\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] log_level = \"notice\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] lua_package_cpath = \"\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] lua_package_path = \"./?.lua;./?/init.lua;\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] lua_socket_pool_size = 30", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] lua_ssl_verify_depth = 1", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] mem_cache_size = \"128m\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_admin_directives = {}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_daemon = \"on\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_http_directives = {}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_optimizations = true", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_proxy_directives = {}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_sproxy_directives = {}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_stream_directives = {}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_user = \"root root\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] nginx_worker_processes = \"auto\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] origins = {}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_database = \"kong\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_host = \"127.0.0.1\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_max_concurrent_queries = 0", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_port = 5432", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_semaphore_timeout = 60000", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_ssl = false", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_ssl_verify = false", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_timeout = 5000", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] pg_user = \"kong\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] plugins = {\"bundled\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] prefix = \"/usr/local/kong/\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] proxy_access_log = \"logs/access.log\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] proxy_error_log = \"logs/error.log\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] proxy_listen = {\"0.0.0.0:8000\",\"0.0.0.0:8443 ssl\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] real_ip_header = \"X-Real-IP\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] real_ip_recursive = \"off\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] router_consistency = \"strict\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] ssl_cipher_suite = \"modern\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] ssl_ciphers = \"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256\"", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] stream_listen = {\"off\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] trusted_ips = {\"0.0.0.0/0\"}", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] upstream_keepalive = 60", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [verbose] prefix in use: /usr/local/kong", "2021/12/25 14:46:52 [debug] resolved Cassandra contact point '192.168.146.129' to: 192.168.146.129"]}
```

I don't know why Cassandra is listening on IP address `192.168.146.129` at port 9042 but it shows this error `connection refuse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're missing a lot of information here to actually solve the problem. We do not know what the script looks like, the configuration of the machine to reproduce the matter at hand, and what the script actually does. Running the script from shell module should in theory work.

Some things you can try:

1.

```yaml
- name: run the script with script
  script: <script_name.sh>
  become: <the_username_running_the_script>
  args:
    chdir: /dir/of/script
```

2. We do not know whether if there are some environment variables set.

Login at the host as the user executing the command, and run `env`. Perhaps you can see some hints there which might lead to a solution.

3. The Ansible output describes: `host seems unhealthy`. Why is this? Can you look at the logs after the script has run?
   Can you run commands at Casandra and try to find out what the health is and search for hints...

Also,

> I don't know why Cassandra is listening on IP address 192.168.146.129 at port 9042

When I look at your netstat output, the first line, I see that there is a Java application listening on that port on that IP... So, it is listening. If you do not know why this is the case, find that out first.