# The subtle difference in an ansible script "SHELL" and the directly running Shell commands on an ubuntu machine 20.04 EC2?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-ec2, ansible, vagrant

I come with a Vagrant script that pulls down an bionic 18 which then runs an ansible playbook which generates two EC2s ubuntu 20.04 which successfully run though every "task:" I assign. I am able to run everything I want in a largely automated download and execution for a publisher subscriber method. **Here is the issue:** I can run my .sh and .py scripts manually and the systems works, but when I use the ansible methods I must be doing something wrong much like these solutions point to:

- [Shell command works on direct hosts but fail on Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70478771/shell-command-works-on-direct-hosts-but-fail-on-ansible)
- [ansible run command on remote host in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347379/ansible-run-command-on-remote-host-in-background)
- https://superuser.com/questions/870871/run-a-remote-script-application-in-detached-mode-in-ansible

What I want to do is simply correct the issue with this, and run it in the background.

```
- name: Start Zookeeper
  shell: sudo /usr/local/kafka-server/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  /usr/local/kafka-server/config/zookeeper.properties </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
- name: Sleep for 30 seconds and continue with play
  wait_for:
    timeout: 15
- name: Start Kafka broker
  shell: sudo /usr/local/kafka-server/bin/kafka-server-start.sh  /home/ubuntu/usr/local/kafka-server/config/server.properties </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I have tried it with just a single **"&"** at the end as well as passing in explicit calls to my user account **"ubuntu"**. I've used the **"become: yes"**. I really don't want to use a daemon especially since others seem to have used this successfully before.

I do want to note that a glaring sign to you that I can't seem to think through is that it hangs when I don't include the &, but if I do include the & it just outright fails, which made me think it was running, but the script won't proceed because these are listener processes.

```
#     - name: Start Zookeeper
#       become: yes
#       script: /usr/local/kafka-server/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh
#       args: 
#         chdir: /usr/local/kafka-server/config/zookeeper.properties
```

This failed, and I'd rather not create another script to copy over the directories and localize it if there is a simple solution to the first block of code.

Multiple ways to skin this cat, but I'd rather just have my mistake on the shell ansible command fixed, and I don't see it.

Comment: 1) We have no idea which errors you are facing 2) never use `sudo` in a shell task, use `become: true` 3) `chdir` should point to a.... dir, not a file 4) using `&` will run a process in the background but it will still be attached to the current terminal and die as soon as it exists (i.e. when the ansible task is done) 5) do yourself a favor, register zookeeper and kafka as services in systemd and use the dedicated ansible module to control them 6) If you intend to run zookeeper directly, see point 5. 7) if you deliberately intend to ignore point 5, read `man nohup`.

Comment: 1. indeed, this is a frustrating part that I cannot get to show with debug mode. It does try to run it, but it technically doesn't break it just terminates the process. no errors to my knowledge has ever shown. 4-7 are basically the answers to the question.  Thank you! I appreciate it, and I didn't realize that it would force that shell session shut, but that does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the answers written in your third link:

https://superuser.com/questions/870871/run-a-remote-script-application-in-detached-mode-in-ansible

This happens because the script process is a child process from the shell spawned by ansible. To keep the process running after ansible has finished you would need to disown this child process.

The proper way to do this is configuring the software (zookeeper in your case) as a service. There are plenty of examples for this such as:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/979498/how-to-start-a-zookeeper-daemon-after-booting-under-specific-user-in-ubuntu-serv

Once you have configured it as a service, you can start it or stop it using ansible [service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) module.